# How to render a Jira Issue in Qt Application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, jira, pyside2

I am using the **[Jira Python API](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/)** and have a **PySide2 (Qt5) Application** that needs to display Jira issues when a user selects items from a view.

If possible, I'd like to just display exactly what any issue looks like when you browse to it, **minus the navbars** on the side and top of the issue. Screenspace is an issue with this app, so this is important.

I'm a little unclear on the best way to do this. The way I see it I have two options:

1. Use the `QWebEngineView` and display the URL directly. But I can't currently find any documentation on how to retrieve that URL without navbars. To me this is the simplest option, and preferable.
2. Render the issues myself in a `QLabel`, `QTextEdit`, or some custom widget.

#1 is preferable for a number of reasons, so is there a URL I can provide to `QWebEngineView` that can render without the navbars?

```
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
url = 'https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-26418'
view = QWebEngineView()
view.load(url)
view.show()
```

If this isn't possible, what's the most straightforward way to render the issue myself in a comparable layout?

Is there an easier 3rd option I'm not considering?

I'll add the disclaimer - I do more desktop app development and have only a limited experience with web-development. So would appreciate any details on anything I need to utilize outside of python/PySide/Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP points out, one possible option is to use QWebEngineView and javascript can be used to remove components like the navbar:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class QJiraViewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        source_code = """
// @include https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-*

var target = document.getElementById("page");
var e = document.getElementById("header");
e.hidden = true;
if( target != null){
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var elements = mutation.target.getElementsByClassName("aui-sidebar projects-sidebar fade-in");
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var e = elements.item(i);
                e.hidden = true;
                e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
            }
        });
    });
    var config = {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };
    observer.observe(target, config);
}
"""

        script = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineScript()
        script.setInjectionPoint(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineScript.DocumentReady)
        script.setName("remove_elements")
        script.setRunsOnSubFrames(False)
        script.setSourceCode(source_code)
        self.view.page().profile().scripts().insert(script)

    def load(self, url):
        self.view.load(url)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QJiraViewer()
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-26418"))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Beatiful, simple, elegant solution. Works perfectly in the latest versions of PySide2 in my standalone implementation. 

The one unfortunate piece of the puzzle for me is that this app is also being embedded within a few other Qt applications, one of which (I only learned after trying this code) uses an older version of PySide2 which appears to be lacking the scripts() method of QWebEngineProfile (though appears to have all other components). 

As noted - web dev is not my expertise so not well versed in QWebEngine - are you aware if there was an older method this replaced?

Comment: @stowaway If you don't tell me the version of PySide2 that you use then it's difficult to try to help

Comment: The app with the problematic distribution is using 2.0.0~alpha0